Typesafe Kotlin DSL NavGraph throws IllegalStateException
I am playing with the new Kotlin DSL Navigation Compose plugin, but I get an exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find startDestination com.perissf.myapp.SignIn from NavGraph. Ensure the starting NavDestination was added with route from KClass.

Composable
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = SignIn,
) {
    // if I remove the following lines calling NavGraphBuilder.composable() extension function, I get the exception
    composable<SignIn> {  
        SignInScreen()
    }
    signInDestination()        
}

SignInNavigation.kt
@Serializable
object SignIn

fun NavGraphBuilder.signInDestination () {
    composable<SignIn> {
        SignInScreen()
    }
}

The weird thing is that if I remove the call to the extension function NavGraphBuilder.composable, as detailed in the code comment, I get the exception; if I keep it, it works fine, but in the end it should do the same thing as the call to signInDestination() extension function written by me.
Using cutting-edge library androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.8.0-beta04@aarand following line by line this Android Developers guide: Encapsulate your navigation code

Are you using the same composable import in both files?

@ianhanniballake sure:  androidx.navigation.compose.composable in both files

And if the signInDestination() method is in the same file as your NavHost, does it still not work then?

@ianhanniballake your hint lead me to the right direction: indeed when moving the extension to the new file, I erroneously left the @Serializable object SignIn in both places, and was importing the wrong one. Now it works fine. Thanks!!!

The error message indicates that the specific class, the one you use when you type startDestination = SignIn is not present in the navigation graph - i.e., there is not any composable<SignIn> that is using that exact same SignIn object.
Make sure that you are referencing the exact same object by checking imports in your files - a good test is to move the extension method into the same file and see if that works, then try it again in its new location.
